# Cannot boot to windows 10 m2 after installing linux on separate ssd

Tags: boot, windows, ssd, m2

My windows 10 is installed on m2 ssd (UEFI).
Today i have installed ubuntu on separate sata ssd (UEFI).
Now i cannot boot windows 10 from boot options list.
If i choose m2 from list there is a message 
 **Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key**
Is there a way to boot windows 10? Thanks!

Comment: Problem solved
I just reinstall windows on m2 again and **windows boot manager** option is now available in bios boot list.

Answer (score 0):

Update the available Operating Systems in the boot configuration:

`sudo update-grub`

Then reinstall the Boot Loader if it looks correct (you should see windows there):

`sudo grub-install /dev/sda`

Note that **/dev/sda** represents the first bootable drive. Re-installing the Windows Boot loader will destroy the Grub boot loader leaving you unable to access Linux.

Comment: Grub loader was not showing from the beginning.
i did sudo update-grub but nothing.
Then i reinstalled windows on m2 and now windows boot manage is available in boot list.
and Linux is booting by default now.
So both windows and linux are working now

Comment: Usually you would have needed to install the boot loader to the drive in linux because windows doesn't play nice with any other boot loader and destroys anything else on install. Maybe the new windows 10 boot loader handels it now, I'm not sure. Can you clarify this?